# Why does my JAVA for loop work with shorter numbers, but continues to loop with longer numbers?

Tags: java, for-loop, modulo

I am trying to get back the proper exponent, and this program works when I plug in the example numbers(exampleA, exampleB, exampleP) as they return the value they should, but when I plug in the long numbers(A, B, p), the loop continues. I believe I should be getting 2099 when plugging in B and p. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //g = 5//
        //let i run from 0 to p -1//
        //compute g^a mod p and see if it is A, if you find A, then a is the solution for A//
        //compute g^a mod p and see if it is B, if you find B, then a is the solution for B//
        long A = 1958258942L;
        long B = 670001116L;
        long p = 3267000013L;
        //example p to plug in for example a and example b//
        long exampleP = 23;
        //plugging this in should return 4//
        long exampleA = 4;
        //plugging this in should return 3//
        long exampleB = 10;
        int newNum;
        int a = 0;
        int g = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < (p - 1); i++) {
                a = i;
                System.out.println(a);
                newNum = powMod(g, a, exampleP);
                if (newNum == exampleB) break;
            }
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    
    public static int powMod(int g, int exponent, long p) {
        int result = 1;

        while (exponent > 0)
        {
            // exponent is odd
            if (exponent % 2 == 1)
            {
                result = (int) ((result * g) % p);
            }

            // divide exponent in half
            exponent /= 2;

            // square base and take remainder 
            g = (int) ((g * g) % p);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p` is quite high. About 3 billion.

An `int` only goes just above 2 billion, it can never reach 3 billion.

In `for (int i = 0; i < (p - 1); i++)`, `i` is an `int`, so `i` is definitely not greater than 2147483647, `i` cannot ever reach `p - 1` which is about 3 billion. `i` will become negative before that, and start counting up to zero, past zero, up to just over 2 billion, and then still never reach 3 billion. So the loop condition is always true, and the loop never ends.

Simple solution: make `i` a `long`.

There are also bugs in `powMod`, the products (not just the remainders) must be done as `long`s otherwise they can wrap modulo 2<sup>32</sup> *before* being reduced modulo `p` (and the product as an `int` can be negative, which does not combine well with how remainders in Java work with negative inputs). For example `(int) ((g * g) % p)` should be `(int) (((long)g * g) % p)` (see below for further modification)

`modPow` accepts an `int` as exponent, but if the loop is fixed to actually loop from 0 to `p - 1` then the exponent would need to be a `long` too. Alternatively it could stay an `int`, but then it needs to be treated as an unsigned integer, that would take more changes to the code.

The highest that an intermediate product (a product before being reduced modulo `p`) could be is 3267000012² (both operands of the product can be `p - 1` at most). That does not fit in 63 bits, so as a `long` it could be negative, which means you need `Long.remainderUnsigned​` instead of the `%` operator. The product does fit in 64 bits, so there's still no need for `BigInteger`.
So use something like `Long.remainderUnsigned​((long)g * g, p)`

In this case you could avoid `powMod` entirely, and rather than computing `modPow(g, i, p)` from scratch in every iteration, compute that by multiplying the previous value by `g` (mod `p`).

Comment: Thank you! It worked and I got the proper exponent(a) when plugging in A and p, but now I need to take A^a mod p (which should return 18), but when I try to use modPow again, it returns a large number. Any tips for that? Thank you for the great explanation.

Comment: @wawa why should A^a mod p be 18 and what did you get instead?

Comment: I am working on a diffie helman encryption, so the exponent(a) you get from the loop when (newNum ==A) can be used like B^a mod p to get the key 18. And the exponent you get when (newNum == B) can be used like A^a mod p to get the same value key. I am getting 991719370 instead for both B and A, so at least the shared key is the same, but I know it should be 18.

Comment: @wawa computing a discrete logarithm (which is what we did here) is not part of Diffie Hellman usually, so I'm still not quite sure what you're doing, but I can tell you that (all mod p) 5^571 = A and 5^2099 = B, and A^2099 and B^571 are the same (which would be your key, you don't choose the key in DH, both parties choose some secret and then a shared key is made from both of them). 5^(571*2099) (which is what both parties find as the shared key) is 991719370

Comment: I found it!! you have to take (A/B^a mod p) mod 26 (26 for each key in the alphabet, 0-25). 991719370 mod 26 is 18 :) Thanks again for the help, I understand this stuff way better now.